# Expression must be a modifiable lvalue (when attempting to append to an array)

Tags: c++, lvalue

I have the following:

```
uint16_t Hitcount[64]; //64-byte array buffer 
uint16_t Br; 
int StdWidth = 38;
int widthpad = 8;
int W;
uint16_t blocks;


if (W <= (StdWidth + widthpad) && W >= (StdWidth - widthpad) && blocks == 1) {
        Hitcount += Br;
    }
```

My goal is to appenf "Br" to the array "Hitcount" if "W" is within a certain range. However, "Hitcount" is indicating the error "Expression must be a modifiable lvalue". Don't I have my data types and everything in order?

Apologies if this is too close to other questions that have been posted. I looked at them but could not relate them to this scenario with my limited knowledge.

Comment: What do you expect `Hitcount += Br;` to do?

Comment: First of all, your comments are misleading. It is a 128-byte array buffer. Second of all, if you want to append something to the array, you need to change the value of a certain element of it, not increment the array object itself - it is meaningless operation.

Comment: To append Br to the array Hitcount, as described here:  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAppendOperator

Comment: ...strings aren't c-style arrays

Comment: the name of a static array evaluates to the address of the array which is not an lvalue, as the compiler is trying to point that out with an error.

Comment: In the example you've provided, it is Sring object which is being appended to, not C-style array of uint16_t elements...

Comment: @LegitimateWorkUser An array is not a string.  I suggest you consult the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) on how arrays work.

Comment: @bkVnet, it does not evaluate to it. It decays to it in certain contexts.

Comment: Downvotes? Wow, I should not have asked.

Comment: @SergeyA Probably a wrong wording from my side, but even so isn't that going to be a prvalue in this context?

Comment: @bkVnet, it is a prvalue indeed. However, it is not an address of this array. As a matter of fact, be it the address of the array, it would be incrementable! :)

Comment: @SergeyA Got you!! Oh, the irony!! :)

Comment: Thanks everybody. My degree is not in CS, so I appreciate being set straight. Most of my experience with arrays comes from mathematica, which is more flexible when it comes to lists and vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Hitcount += Br;
```

You cannot add value to a C style array like that. You either need to maintain elements count and add a value like this:

```
Hitcount[count++] = Br;
```

or you better use `std::vector` and add element by calling `push_back`:

```
std::vector<uint16_t> Hitcount;
// code skipped
Hitcount.push_back( Br );
```

Comment: Thaanks, I didn't realize += was for string arrays only. It would be easy to track the elements and append by their count numbers. I'll do that.

Comment: @LegitimateWorkUser C style string array is `char str[size]` and would have exactly the same issue. What you mention is C++ object `std::string`which is not string array but an object, so `std::vector` is an object as well and has functionality to dynamically add elements etc.

Comment: Thanks, Slava. I'm using std:: <vector> now and it's already working.

Answer (score 1):

Plain C/C++ arrays cannot be extended the way `string` objects can. Look into using `std::vector`.

Comment: Yes, this is working for me now. I certainly appreciate it.